# Как ограничить количество выводимых новостей с сайта?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Еще было бы интересно узнать как выводить их вместе с ссылками на эти новости.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://habr.com/ru/hub/python/")
page = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

headings = map(lambda e: e.text, soup.select("h2.post__title"))
for h in headings:
  print(h)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу тут ни одной причины для использования `map`. Упрощайте.

Вывод можно ограничить остановкой цикла вывода. В толк не возьму, что именно вы имеете ввиду про ограничение колличества выводимых статей. Может, это только мне кажется слишком легким, чтобы это было правильным ответом? `for title in titles[ :3 ]:` выведет до трех заголовков.

Посмотрев html код можно понять, что следует получить `<a class="post__title_link", ..>`, содержащий как заголовок статьи, так и ссылку на нее.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://habr.com/ru/hub/python/")
page = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select("a.post__title_link")[ :2 ]:
    print(item.text, ">>", item.attrs["href"])
```

```
Как трекать людей в масках или универсальный подход к трекингу объектов произвольной природы >> https://habr.com/ru/post/520628/
Масштабируемая классификация данных для безопасности и конфиденциальности >> https://habr.com/ru/company/skillfactory/blog/520376/
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выводить не все. Нужно map объект преобразовать в list например и потом задать ограничение в цикле:

```
headings = list(map(lambda e: e.text, soup.select("h2.post__title")))
for h in range(2):
   print(headings[h])
```

Чтобы выводить вместе ссылками, я в начале создал список словарей. Каждый словарь содержит название и ссылку.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    response = requests.get("https://habr.com/ru/hub/python/")
    page = response.text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('h2', class_='post__title')
    headings = []
    for item in items:
        headings.append({'link':item.find('a' ,class_='post__title_link').get('href'),
                         'title':item.find('a' ,class_='post__title_link').get_text(strip=True)})
    
    
    for h in range(2):
        print(headings[h]['title'], end="   ")
        print(headings[h]['link'], end="\n\n")
```